# Prove by Induction that $e^{nx}=(e^x)^n$

Tags: real-analysis

Working on an assignment but I've run into a stumbling block!  I've got a couple of problems that I don't know how to do!  The problems are attempting to have you define the $\log$ and $\exp$ functions. Thanks in advance!  I can't wait to be done with this Analysis course!

Things I have already proven:

For any $ x \in (0,\infty)$, define $L(x)=\int_{1}^x {1\over t} dt$

$L(1/x)=-L(x)$

$L(x)$ is invertible and its inverse is $E(x)$

$E'(x)=E(x)$

$L(ax)=L(x)+L(a)$

$E(y+z)=E(y)E(x)$

**Part A:**

Let n be a positive integer.  Prove by induction that $E(nx)=E(x)^n$.

**Part B:**

Deduce from (a) that we also have $E(-nx)=E(x)^{-n}$, so (a) holds for all integers n.

Comment: Do you know what the structure of a proof by induction is?  Did you check the base case, and try to set up the inductive step?  I suggest using $(n+1)x=nx + x$ and $ 0 = nx - nx$ for parts A and B, respectively.

Comment: Hint:
Part A:
$E((n-1)x+x) = E((n-1)x)E(x)$
Part B:
Prove E(0) = 1 and then from part A, what is $E(nx+ (-nx))$?

Comment: Please do not delete you question. This posting could be helpful to someone else in future

Answer (score 1):

The statement is clearly true for n=1. Assume it to be true for n=k, i.e., $E(kx)=E(x)^k$.
Then the statement follows for n=k+1 as $E((k+1)x)=E(kx+x)=E(kx)E(x)=E(x)^k.E(x)$, and we are done.

Part B follows immediately because $E(0)=E(-nx+nx)=E(-nx)E(nx)$. But $E(0)=1$  as $L(1)=0$.

Comment: Alternatively, $E(0)=1$ follows from $E(x+0)=E(x)E(0)$.

Comment: Can you show me why it is true for n=1?  I'm sorry, but that's where I'm having trouble!  I just don't understand how k becomes the exponent.

Comment: E(1x)=E(x)=E(x)^1.